# How to have access to the field from another model in signal?

Tags: django

How to have access to the `path_after` field in signal?

models:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    path = models.FileField(upload_to="src")
    path_after = models.FileField(upload_to="files",blank=True, null=True)

class Document(models.Model):
    rootfile = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    content = models.TextField()
```

signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Store)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        document = Document()
        document.rootfile = kwargs['instance']

        #how to open file from path_after field?
        text_file = open("path_after", "r")

        document.content = #should be text from path_after file, this is TextField
        document.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `instance` in the signal handler which is object of `Store` and it has the `path_after` field. You can access it directly as:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Store)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        document = Document()
        document.rootfile = kwargs['instance']

        #how to open file from path_after field?
        text_file = open(kwargs['instance'].path_after.path, "r")
        ...
```

Comment: Great. Thanks `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FieldFile found`. I can't read this file. How to fix it?

Comment: @user2426362, Make sure your are using `kwargs['instance'].path_after.path` to open file. Last `.path` is important, which gives you required file path.

Answer (score 1):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Store)
def my_handler(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        document = Document()
        document.rootfile = instance

        #how to open file from path_after 
        text_file = open(instance.path_after, "r")

        document.content = #should be text from path_after file, this is TextField
        document.save()
```